# React Hook Form and Zod validattion error kicks off as soon as the form loads. Why?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, zod

I am trying to validate my form field which is basically a tags input field that returns an array.
Here's how I am setting up the form:

```
  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState: { errors, isValid },
  } = useForm<FieldValues>({
    defaultValues: {
      title: "",
      description: "",
      topics: [],
    },
    mode: "onChange",
    resolver: zodResolver(FormValidation),
  });
```

Here's the zod validation configuration:

```
export const CreateQuestionValidation = z.object({
  title: z
    .string()
    .min(10, "Title is too short")
    .max(150, "Title cannot be longer than 150 characters"),
  description: z
    .string()
    .min(50, "Description is too short")
    .max(1500, "Description cannot be longer than 1500 characters")
    .trim(),
  topics: z
    .array(
      z
        .string()
        .min(3, "Each topic must be at least 3 characters long")
        .max(30, "Each topic cannot be longer than 30 characters")
    )
    .min(1, "Enter at least 1 Topic")
    .max(3, "Maximum of 3 Topics are allowed"),
});
```

The problem is, as soon as the form loads, i get the error:

```
"Enter at least 1 Topic"
```

from the topics field. Other fields are behaving correctly but why does the topics field throw error when the form loads.

```
            <Controller
              name="topics"
              control={control}
              render={({ field: { name, onChange, value } }) => (
                <MultiTagsInputField
                  name={name}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  value={value}
                  label="Topics"
                  errors={errors}
                  required
                  placeHolder="Maximum of 3 topics"
                />
              )}
            />
```

And inside the Input field container I have this:

```
  const [tags, setTags] = useState<string[]>(value || []);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    onChange(tags);
  }, [tags]);
```

Does the zod validation work differently for arrays? What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Use [superRefine](https://zod.dev/?id=superrefine) to achieve this.

```
  topics: z.array(
            z.string()
            .min(3, "Each topic must be at least 3 characters long")
            .max(30, "Each topic cannot be longer than 30 characters"))
            .superRefine((arr, ctx) => {
    if (arr.length === 0) {
      ctx.addIssue({
        path: ["topics"],
        code: "custom",
        fatal: true,
        message: "Enter at least 1 Topic",
      });
    }

    const hasValue = arr.some((item) => item.length > 0);

    if (!hasValue) {
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        const item = arr[i];

        if (item.length === 0) {
          ctx.addIssue({
            path: [i],
            code: "custom",
            fatal: true,
            message: "Enter at least 1 Topic",
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }),
```

Comment: Does it really have to be this complex?

Comment: Also, if I implement this solution, the error message goes away but the error condition is still true.

Comment: Can you update your question with the `MultiTagsInputField` component?